# Basic Server for android

Tags: applications, web-server

I want to set up a server on android. Anyone know how to do that? I do not have root. I do know about I-jetty. So any other ideas. Preferably where I learn how to make a server program. I can program in C, bash, etc. for android. I want to be able basically to run a "basic" server program (like Apache). All the program needs to do is host one page on port 8080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App your looking for is [kWS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws&hl=en). It will serve any html file you have on your phone to port 8080 (or other unused port), and it doesn't require a root.

If you want to run a custom server (i.e. with sockets), you'd need to develop your own app with [sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html), although you'll need to know Java.

Comment: I don't know java. And I dont know networking.

Comment: @yuxuantim You dont need to know Java, install [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws&hl=en) app, and put an html file on the directory you set in the app.

Comment: @yuxuantim Check out [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smartphones/host-sites-and-share-files-via-the-kws-android-web-server) tutorial using kWS

Answer (score 1):

If you know PHP, then you may use [PAW Server for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver). It requires the installation of PHP plugin. [Here](http://paw-android.fun2code.de) is the official site.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [Palapa Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfanla.android.pws). It can serve both static and dynamic content as it has PHP and MySQL embedded.